# Stretching text in div

Tags: css, html

I have a div with width set to 500px.
I want the text to be stretched so that it can fit the whole div.
How can this be achieved (if possible) in css ?

Comment: Stretch how? By actual stretching, or by increasing the spaces between the letters?

Comment: @Pekka by increasing the spaces between the letter so it div in the entire div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what I was looking for. I can achieve the stretching with the css property:

```
letter-spacing
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4VQJ9/).

`text-align:justify` your `p` tag

Answer (score 0):

Set `padding` to `0`:

```
div {padding: 0}
```

If there is something in your div, like `<div><p>...</p></div>`, add:

```
div > p {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: padding set to 0 does not stretch the text :(

Comment: Ok, so you cannot do it with CSS (even with `text-align:justify`).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can do that with CSS.

Comment: is the text dynamic? can you just make an image containing the text and then include it?  Adobe software generally has a way to make the text fit the full width in the way you describe.

Comment: @Dan-Baylis: "make an image containing the text" ? Users won't be able to increase text size, and screen readers won't be able to read it. It is a bad idea for accessibility

Comment: Agreed - if those requirements then an image wouldn't be much good.